# Shapefile of Russian forest zones

Tags: geospatial, russia

I want to download a shapefile of forests in Russia by forests zone. Ideally a joint shapefile of forests and Russian administrative regions.

Can you give me a link to it?

[image]

Comment: Have you done any research on your own? If so, where are you stuck?

Comment: 10 second search shows me this: http://www.iiasa.ac.at/web/home/research/researchPrograms/EcosystemsServicesandManagement/RussianForests.en.html